# Restricting the number of rows in Report

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I have a BusinessObjects report, and in Business Layer in "Query options" I have set the property to show me the data set up to 1000 rows.

However, when I run the query I get around 150000 rows with around 1000 pages.

Obviously, the property I wanted to edit is not done in Business Layer -> Query options.

The question is where can I do it?
(I am using BO 4.0 version)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDT to set the result limit, you are in the right place.  Make sure that in addition to filling in the limit you have also checked the accompanying checkbox.

If you are using the SL SDK to set the result limit, use these two methods:

```
BusinessLayer.setResultSetSizeLimited(boolean value)   //equivalent to checking or unchecking the checkbox
BusinessLayer.setResultSetSizeLimit(long value)   //equivalent to filling in the limit number
```

As always, save and publish to see the results in WebI.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the checkbox of "Limit size of result set to":
[image]
(**image taken from https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/18/basics-of-information-design-tool-part-2-properties/**)